# Page getting refreshed on entering incorrect username/password without displaying error message

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am using ajax to submit the loginform and check if the credentials are correct.When I enter the correct username and password,it logs in successfully but when I enter incorrect username/password the page gets refreshed without displaying any message. I am unable to  determine the reason behind it.Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

```
<form action=""  method="post" id="login-form">
  <div class="login_fields">
     <label>Email</label>
     <input  name="your_email" id="user-name" type="email" class="required textfield" autofocus required>
    <label>Password</label>
     <input  name="your_password" id="password"  type="password"                    class="required textfield" required>
    <div class="login_buttons">
          <button type="submit" class="contact-send contact-button" >Login</button>
          <a   class="register-button">Register</a>
     </div>
  </div>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $(".contact-send").click(function()
    {
       $.ajax({
                          url: "/index/loginform",
                          data: $("#login-form").serialize() + "&action=send",
                          type: "post",
                          cache: false,
                          dataType: "html",
                          success : function(resp)
                          {
                    if(resp=="send-1")
                        {
                      alert("invalid username/password");
                    }
                                  },
             error : function(error,st,e)
                {
                   console.log(error,st,e); 
                }
            });
            });
   });
    </script>
```

Comment: This path '/../loginform' is going to cause some problems...

Comment: I have set the url as "/index/loginform"

Comment: and that's a valid path? Does the web-server account have permission to access files there?

Comment: Yes ,it does.If the credentials are correct it successfully logs in but fails to show any error if the given incorrect credentials.

Comment: Possibly a (mis)use of a reserved word? ('data')

Comment: I have updated my code according to the suggestions given by all.Please go through it .

Comment: @Chetan Your login button class name will be `contact-send contact-button`.But you used `contact-send` and why ?

Comment: Can you post your `server side code` ?

Comment: Kite Player : I have used `contact-button` class for some other purpose.

Answer (score 1):

When you "alert" an error then it will just translate it to a string which is `[object Object]`, try `console.log`ging the error instead.

Comment: I have tried using console.log(error+st+e).I get the same error.

Comment: @ChetanGawai use commas.... using the `+` will only translate to a string. `console.log(error, st, e);`

Comment: The page is getting refreshed .I am not able to see the the what console.log(error,st,r) prints properly.

Comment: if your page is getting refreshed it seems like you did get into you ajax success function, because that's where you tell the page to refresh. Refreshing shouldn't happen when you're doing an ajax request. You might also want to preventDefault() when you submit the form so it doesn't do the default submit.

Comment: Donnywals: Without the location.reload() also the page is getting refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Alert the DATA you are getting in response from your ajax page. Try to print in console.log to check. It will print the Object in console

Comment: Hey Chetan, In that case,Check your AJAX page try to access directly rather then AJAX CALL (For testing only) and print your data in console.See if your getting the desired output or not, then try AJAX Call pattern

Answer (score 0):

Add return false; ?

```
success : function(resp)
{
        if(resp=="send-1"){
            alert("invalid username/password"););
            return false;   
        }
},
error : function(error,st,e)
{
    console.log(error,st,e);
    return false;   
}
```

Comment: since the button type is submit button, the form will get submitted by default if you have not force it to not submit.. or else you can change the button type to just "button"

Comment: Roy MJ : I have made changes to my code according to your suggestions ,still the problem persists.

Comment: Hi Roy MJ : Thanks for the suggestion.It was left by mistake while editing the code on stack overflow.My main code has proper brackets.